# Get a img src , and then modify the div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this html

```
<div class="mytext">
blablabla
</div>

<div class="part2" data-type="background" data-speed="10">
    <img src="images/bb4.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="mytext">
hello hello world
</div>

<div class="part2"    data-type="background" data-speed="10">
    <img src="images/bb5.jpg" />
</div>
```

now i want to get each src of the images in part2 container, and then change the html to this result

```
<div class="mytext">
blablabla
</div>

<div class="part2" style="background:url('images/bb4.jpg') fixed;" data-type="background" data-speed="10">

</div>

<div class="mytext">
hello hello world
</div>

<div class="part2" style="background:url('images/bb5') fixed;" data-type="background" data-speed="10">

</div>
```

basicly i have to get the src and then edit the attributes of the div container,  and delete the img tag ,and i have to do this on the load of the page

i've write this piece of code to get the src, but it doesn't work , and there isn't the part of changing the div

```
var elems = [].slice.call( document.getElementsByClassName("post2") );
elems.forEach( function( elem ){
    elem.onclick = function(){
        var arr = [],
            imgs = [].slice.call( elem.getElementsByTagName("img") );
        if(imgs.length){
            imgs.forEach( function( img ){
                var attrID = img.id;
                arr.push(attrID);
            });
            alert(arr);
        } else {
            alert("No images found.");
        }
    };
});
```

can someone help me?:) 
thanks

Comment: Do you want the solution in vanilla javascript, or jQuery? Because jQuery isn't being used here but you've tagged it. Also your class name is `part2`, but you've called `getElementsByClassName` on `post2` instead

Comment: a jsbin or jsfiddle link would make us help you more..

Comment: You wrote this "piece of code to get the src" ... you don't even mention "src" anywhere in your Javascript code

Comment: `var attrID = img.id;` - images in the code posted do not have an `id` attribute. If you want to extract the image `src` then use `img.src`.

Comment: [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BnvEG/) sorry guys i've copied the wrong piece of code

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.part2').each(function(){
  img = $(this).find('img');  
  $(this).css({'background': 'url(' +   img.attr('src') + ') fixed'});
  img.remove();
});
```

Comment: perfect this is what i was searching for:) ! thank you very much!

Comment: @GiorgioRomano you might want to check if the `img` actually exists otherwise it will fail.

Comment: @Kyra good point, something like

if($(this).find(img).length){
..
} else {
...
}

?

Answer (score 0):

SInce you have added Jquery tag. [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/HD986/2/) is the answer in jquery.

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $('.part2').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('style','background:url(\''+ $(this).find('img').attr('src')+'\') fixed;');
        $(this).find('img').remove();
    });
});
```

or

```
 $('#test').click(function(){
        $('.part2').each(function(){
            $(this).css('background','url(\''+ $(this).find('img').attr('src')+'\') fixed');
            $(this).find('img').remove();
        });
    });
```

Comment: All answers are similar but this one is with example. so +1 for this.

Comment: Instead of setting `styel`(typo?) attribute, you can use `.css()` method.

Comment: ya we can even that was pretty easier. but i did it according to requirement.

Comment: @undefined ya that was a typo